# Dropdown Menus with Auto List-Item Widths

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

So I'm working on a drop menu and I'd like each menu item to have an auto width. i.e. the background to expand to the width of the menu item rather than having an overall fixed width for all the UL. I thought that giving the ul li an auto width would sort it but it seems not. What am I missing?

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a class="last" href="#">MENU &#9660;</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Very Long</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
#nav { 
height: 1; 
list-style-type: none; 
padding-top: 1.25em; 
margin-top: 0em;
}

#nav li { 
float: right; 
position: relative; padding: 0;
} 

#nav li a { 
display: block; 
font-size: 14px; 
padding: 0 1em;  
margin-bottom: 1em; 
color: #333; 
text-decoration: none; 
border-left: 1px solid #333; 
}

#nav .last, #nav li ul li a {
border-left: none;
}

#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:focus {
color: #666;
}

#nav li ul { 
opacity: 0; 
position: absolute; 
right: 0em; 
list-style-type: none; 
padding: 0; margin: 0; 
}

#nav li:hover ul { 
opacity: 1; 
}

#nav li ul li { 
float: none; 
position: static; 
width: auto; 
height: 0; 
line-height: 0; 
background: none; 
text-align: right; 
margin-bottom: .75em;
}

#nav li:hover ul li { 
height: 25px; 
line-height: 2.5em;
}

#nav li ul li a { 
background: #222; 
}

#nav li ul li a:hover { 
color: #666; 
}
```

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your #nav li style is being applied to all child li elements, so you need to use the ">", which selects only the immediate child.

Here is updated CSS which fixes the problem.  I also commented out some other CSS that was interfering:

```
#nav { 
    height: 1; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding-top: 1.25em; 
    margin-top: 0em;
}

#nav > li {  /* Added ">" */
    float: right; 
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
} 

#nav li a { 
    display: inline-block; /* was block */ 
    font-size: 14px; 
    padding: 0 1em;  
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
    color: #333; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-left: 1px solid #333; 
}

#nav .last, #nav li ul li a {
    border-left: none;
}

#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:focus {
    color: #666;
}

#nav li ul { 
    opacity: 0; 
    /*position: absolute; 
    right: 0em; */
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0; margin: 0; 
}

#nav li:hover ul { 
    opacity: 1; 
}

#nav li ul li { 
    /*float: none; 
    position: static; 
    width: auto;*/ 
    height: 0; 
    line-height: 0; 
    background: none; 
    text-align: right; 
    margin-bottom: .75em;
}

#nav li:hover ul li { 
    height: 25px; 
    line-height: 2.5em;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome - thanks.  I was using Sass, and I learnt that you can just add the '>' char before the element in a sass structure too. (with a space between the '>' and 'li'.

So like:

.nav {
  > ul { }
}

Answer (score 3):

You are using `display: block` for your links.  That causes them to fill the available space.  That's why they are all the same width.  And `float: right` is contributing to the general narrowness.  Use `inline-block` instead of `block` and prevent the link wrapping by using `white-space: nowrap`:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/neJty/2/

Comment: Nice one! One question though....is it possible to edit the link target/rollover area i.e. the amount of space/padding around the link that causes the drop to kick in?

Comment: @Jedda - Sure, of course.  You would do this by changing the size of the element that has the `:hover` selector.