# Increase selectOneMenu options width automatically?

Tags: css, primefaces, selectonemenu

I need to allow my Dropdown SubMenu to increase it's width automatically when I save any data with really long names. The dropdown box adjust itself weirdly in respond to my current code. (Image shown below)
P/S: My dropdown has to work on both Chrome and Firefox.

I tried many ways to solve it but I'm still stuck. May I know what are some other ways using CSS to solve this?
I tried changing float to `float: left` but it's not correct for me as I do not want to have the left-to-right scrollbar. 
**For submenu, if the data in it is really long, it doesn't matter if the alignment of the sub-menu doesn't align with the Main menu.** What I need is auto increment of width.

Below is my code:

```
.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label {
   background: #c9e9e2 !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-list {
   background: #c9e9e2 !important;
   -webkit-padding-end: 0px !important;   
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   -webkit-column-width: 150px !important; /*words inside dropdown*/

   /*For Firefox*/
   -moz-column-width: 158px !important; 
}

.ui-selectonemenu-item.ui-selectonemenu-list-item.ui-state-highlight {
   background:#FFFFFF !important; 
   text-shadow: none;
   color: #444444;    
}

.selectOneMenu {
   color: #444444;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-weight: 400;
   height: 21px;
   width: 158px !important;
}
```

As you can see from the image here, all the first letter from each word are being cut off.

[image]

Comment: I had many cases where the clients wanted to adjust this component, I even had to write some composite components based on this, doing it only by CSS is fairly undoable, since the original component's style is being altered by [jQuery](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5bf2aff8e699c43ebd3c23626279d07f3e0cf75a/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js#L498), if jQuery is not an option for you it's might be hard. And yes you can make it globally effective with jQuery.

Comment: @HatemAlimam Hi! Is it possible to place this dropdown jQuery code in the CSS page?

Comment: you seems unfamiliar with jQuery or javascript ! jQuery is a javascript after all, you can include a js file into your template/master page or individual page to do the job...

Comment: @HatemAlimam Sorry I am weak in js! Hmm but I have more than 100 js currently. All pages have dropdown. So if I have to add in jquery dropdown, I would need to add in to all pages?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery might help here, using an if statement, you could have it so the dropdown menu increases its width automatically if the string length of an individual column within the dropdown menu is over a certain amount.

Comment: sorry but I am suppose to use CSS here. Is there any ways using CSS instead of jQuery? Because the CSS file I am using right now is able to affect the other webpages. It may be easier for me to edit the codes on CSS only and make an positive effect to all the other pages, so I do not need to go back to jQuery everytime.

Comment: Oh, apologies! Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591692/dropdown-menus-with-auto-list-item-widths solution what you're looking for?

Comment: FYI @isg, not that there's anything wrong with wanting a CSS solution, but in case you didn't know, you could also have a .js JavaScript file that can affect all other webpages...

Comment: @JWLim Thanks! But my supervisor wants it on CSS so I would need to edit my code on the CSS pages.

Comment: @abeinke Thanks! It works on Chrome. But it doesn't works on Firefox after I add in `float: right;` and `position: relative;`